# Facing problem while getting items using barcode scanner in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a barcode scanning feature using the flutter_barcode_scanner package in my Flutter app. The goal is to scan a barcode, retrieve information about the scanned product from a predefined static map, and display a popup with the product details. However, I'm facing an issue where I can't display any items.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: BarcodeScannerScreen(),
  ));
}

class BarcodeScannerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarcodeScannerScreenState createState() => _BarcodeScannerScreenState();
}

class _BarcodeScannerScreenState extends State<BarcodeScannerScreen> {
  final Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> staticItems = {
    "4523659874586": {
      "itemName": "Masala Masti",
      "itemDescription": "TooYum! Sticks",
      "itemPrice": 20,
    },
    "5263658978452": {
      "itemName": "Waffers",
      "itemDescription": "Balaji Salted Waffers",
      "itemPrice": 10,
    },
    "856363625635": {
      "itemName": "Amul Processed Cheese",
      "itemDescription": "Amul Processed Cheese 500 g",
      "itemPrice": 500,
    },
  };

  String _scannedBarcode = '';

  Future<void> _scanBarcode(BuildContext context) async {
    String barcode = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
      "#ff6666", // Scanner overlay color
      "Cancel", // Cancel button text
      true, // Show flash icon
      ScanMode.BARCODE, // Barcode scan mode
    );

    if (barcode != '-1') {
      setState(() {
        _scannedBarcode = barcode;
      });

      final item = staticItems[barcode];
      if (item != null) {
        _showProductPopup(context, item);
      } else {
        _showErrorPopup(context);
      }
    }
  }

  void _showProductPopup(BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(item['itemName']),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(item['itemDescription']),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text('Price: \$${item['itemPrice'].toStringAsFixed(2)}'),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showErrorPopup(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text('No matching item found for the scanned barcode.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ScanShop - Barcode Scanner'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _scanBarcode(context),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.teal,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 16),
                  elevation: 5,
                  shadowColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Scan Barcode',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              if (_scannedBarcode.isNotEmpty)
                Text(
                  'Scanned Barcode: $_scannedBarcode',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: App screenshot showing an error]

Comment: There is no item with the code it outputs, are you sure your barcode should match to your items?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `staticItems`

and check the error prompt.

no code match.